# Separate Jade, PHP with Gulp

Tags: php, templates, gulp, pug

I’ve found this sample https://github.com/BookArt/jade4php-example 
I’m i’m seeing the possibility to separate PHP logic from the jade code over there. Such that database query's could be done in one php file and assigned to the .jade file.

But our current project uses Gulp build system in stead of Grunt.
Does there exist a similar template (logic separation) library for Gulp?

Comment: I have been able to use the Template class with the .phtml files generated by Gulp. But now I have to use the | <?php echo $param; ?> command to include the variables generated in the php file. The example (https://github.com/BookArt/jade4php-example) that uses Grunt, is able to use a more concise notation :php(echo) $para_1

Anyone has an idea how to make this concise notation work?